# C++ error EXC_BAD_ACCESS static void assign

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers

I am a C++ Newbie, but I can find my way through the code most of the time. So this question might be really stupid, but I am stuck.

I am trying to add javascript bindings for ParticleSystem::initWithFile function in cocos2d-x 3.0beta2 and i am running this on a iOS simulator.

XCode breaks at

```
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    static void assign(char_type& __c1, const char_type& __c2) _NOEXCEPT
    {__c1 = __c2;}
```

This is the function added for javascript bindings.

```
JSBool js_cocos2dx_ParticleSystem_initWithFile(JSContext *cx, uint32_t argc, jsval *vp)
{
    jsval *argv = JS_ARGV(cx, vp);
    JSBool ok = JS_TRUE;
    JSObject *obj = JS_THIS_OBJECT(cx, vp);
    js_proxy_t *proxy = jsb_get_js_proxy(obj);
    cocos2d::ParticleSystem* cobj = (cocos2d::ParticleSystem *)(proxy ? proxy->ptr : NULL);
    JSB_PRECONDITION2( cobj, cx, JS_FALSE, "js_cocos2dx_ParticleSystem_initWithFile : Invalid Native Object");
    if (argc == 1) {
        std::string arg0;
        ok &= jsval_to_std_string(cx, argv[0], &arg0);
        JSB_PRECONDITION2(ok, cx, JS_FALSE, "Error processing arguments");

        cobj->initWithFile(arg0);
        JS_SET_RVAL(cx, vp, JSVAL_VOID);
        return JS_TRUE;
    }

    JS_ReportError(cx, "js_cocos2dx_ParticleSystem_setStartRadiusVar : wrong number of arguments: %d, was expecting %d", argc, 1);
    return JS_FALSE;
}
```

And the function where it breaks is

```
bool ParticleSystem::initWithFile(const std::string& plistFile)
{
    bool ret = false;
    _plistFile = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(plistFile);
    ValueMap dict = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile(_plistFile.c_str());

    CCASSERT( !dict.empty(), "Particles: file not found");

    // XXX compute path from a path, should define a function somewhere to do it
    string listFilePath = plistFile;
    if (listFilePath.find('/') != string::npos)
    {
        listFilePath = listFilePath.substr(0, listFilePath.rfind('/') + 1);
        ret = this->initWithDictionary(dict, listFilePath.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        ret = this->initWithDictionary(dict, "");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Problem seems to be with plistFile variable.

**Update:**
From this line in `ParticleSystem::initWithFile` method, it goes to `std::string` templates

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::operator=(basic_string&& __str)
    _NOEXCEPT_(__alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value &&
               is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value)
{
    __move_assign(__str, integral_constant<bool,
          __alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value>());
    return *this;
}
```

and then to

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
void
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::__move_assign(basic_string& __str, true_type)
    _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value)
{
    clear();
    shrink_to_fit();
    __r_.first() = __str.__r_.first();
    __move_assign_alloc(__str);
    __str.__zero();
}
```

and then

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
void
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::clear() _NOEXCEPT
{
    __invalidate_all_iterators();
    if (__is_long())
    {
        traits_type::assign(*__get_long_pointer(), value_type());
        __set_long_size(0);
    }
    else
    {
        traits_type::assign(*__get_short_pointer(), value_type());
        __set_short_size(0);
    }
}
```

and finally

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
static void assign(char_type& __c1, const char_type& __c2) _NOEXCEPT
    {__c1 = __c2;}
```

Here is the screenshot of XCode
[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Comment: And where's *your* code? Where in *your* code does it break?

Comment: at _plistFile = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(plistFile);

Comment: I have updated the question, I don't know if it helps understand the problem better.

Comment: Most likely is that `cobj ` isn't pointing at a valid object, possibly one that's been destroyed.

Comment: But it does step into cobj->initWithFile and then breaks at FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(plistFile);

Comment: @molbdnilo I am not sure what is happening. Sometimes it breaks at ret = this->initWithDictionary(dict, listFilePath.c_str()); and this time the error is "error: memory read failed for 0x0"

Comment: You can always step into member functions, the code doesn't depend on the object in any way. It definitely sounds like the object is broken. How do you create it?

Comment: It is created in js_cocos2dx_ParticleSystem_initWithFile which gets called from javascript. So you mean the object itself is not created properly and even if cobj is not properly created it can still step in to a member functions?